# Firmware updates for HP DL360 G5 server

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, firmware, firmware-update

DL360 G5 firmware update (BIOS, iLO, etc): From where it should be taken? Most existing links to the HP portal are broken.

Update: HP has moved to new portal (reason why links are broken). However, almost everything is accessible according to accepted answer.

Comment: Why on earth are you still dealing with G5 kit, that model was retired 11 years ago and went of of support 6 years ago - this site is for professionals sorry.

Comment: thank you, Mister Professional

Comment: Is there a correlation between "professionalism" and "end of support for hardware"

Comment: Yes, it's unprofessional to run unsupportable kit in production.

Comment: If cost is a issue I would think to use a profession workstation, like a HPz desktop system and to use an hypervisor on it to replace such old hardware. HP is one of the manufacturer that support for the longer server. They can provide part up to 10 years for a a server even if no warranty. The fact HP retired all the download related to that server model is worring to say the least.

Comment: Sure, next time when small business owner brings me "unsupported" hardware, I will tell them go anykey themselves around the corner, because it is unprofessional.

Comment: @yagmoth555, cost is an issue, always. There are many other reasons not to replace old HW: COVID, economic slowdown, CO2 neutrality and most popular - "it still works"

Comment: no, but if HP does not support them anymore, we can't help much. I seen a customer with a really old server, a worst case than you.  When it died it put them down for 1 weeks, and that costed them a lot, as it was a emergency reinstall and upgrade with third part. If your customer think to upgrade the firmware, it's not because the server behave good too. It's kinda the talk, maybe some were direct, but we try to bring the discussion, but in the end, we can't offer what HP stopped offering

Comment: @yagmoth555, Of course you can. Specialist like you can help in this case. This is why ServerFault exists - to share knowledge. And I appreciate your help. By the way, please check Questions tagged [hp].

Comment: Maybe you can finde someone who kept his downloaded ISO of **ProLiant SPP 2014.06.0** or check https://myenterpriselicense.hpe.com/cwp-ui/free-software/spp_2014.06.0 out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit the HPE Support Center at https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/home

Enter DL360 G5 for your search

Filter by 'Software Downloads' and then sort by date.

Comment: This is a great answer. However, HP does not allow to download the most recent version (why?). Previous taken as the latest available.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Your comment above is off topic and does not answer why HP restricts some downloads.

Comment: It's not off topic if the reason you can't download firmware is because the manufacturer hasn't supported the model for 6 years.

Comment: @JohnDeer Is the question about their "Entitlement Required" policy, if so what specifically is the question? (Presumably beyond their explanation provided on the page)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, well, this is a rhetorical question. I just simply took previous version, which is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

If the links to download firmware are dead, your only hope is to get your hands on a ProLiant Support Pack that does support your server hardware.

I don't have my HPe login near, but check there for older version of it;

[HP Service Pack for ProLiant](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_1d06af9e8a0a4e43b8981b4471#tab-history)

As stated in comments, please advise your customer.

Comment: You have to pay to access PSPs, and HPE won't take money for access to a system they've not supported for more than half a decade.